# How to track when new child element is dynamically added to a div element in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can figure out(call a function) when new element is dynamically added to a div in angularjs?

For eg

```
<div class=parentDiv>
   <div ng-repeat="someLoopingCondition">
        <span ng-if="someCondition">Hello</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are really asking is

> How can i know if a scope variable is changed?

Because that is when a new element is "dynamically" added to your div. When whatever you are iterating over changes.

Also what you call `someLoopingCondition` is not a condition it's a repeat(iteration) expression. And it is probably something along the lines of `item in someScopeVariable`.

So go checkout anular `$scope`'s `$watch` and `$watchCollection` functions.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('someScopeVariable',function(){
    // this callback runs when your array/object changes.
});
```

Check out the documentation of `$watch`and `$watchCollection` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope).